# Encode_JSON Errors in Lasso 8.6.2 After Period of Time

Tags: lasso-lang

We are in the process of converting apps from Lasso 8 to Lasso 9, and as an intermediate step, have upgraded from 8.5.5 to 8.6.2 (which runs alongside 9 on our new box, in [different virtual hosts](http://www.lassosoft.com/Configure-Lasso-8-and-9-Side-by-Side)).

I am finding that with 8.6.2 we are getting a slew of errors on pages that call `encode_json`. The weird thing with these errors is that they don't start happening until some period of time after the site starts. Then, some hours later, all `encode_json` calls begin to fail with error messages like this:

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
Error Information

Error Message: No tag, type or constant was defined under the name "〰〲⵽硜㉻紱硜㉻紳尭筸戵屽筸搵⵽硜" with arguments: array: (pair: (-find)=([\x{0020}-\x{21}\x{23}-\x{5b}\x{5d}-\x{10fff}])), (r)
at: onCompare with params: 'r'
at: JSON with params: 'reload', -Options=array: (-Internal)
at: JSON with params: @map: (reload)=(false), (tcstring)=(LZU), (timestring)=(10:42 AM&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1442Z)
at: [...].lasso with params: 'pageloadtime'='1383038310' on line: 31 at position: 1
Error Code: -9948
```

(Yes, those Chinese(?) characters are in the error message.) I have removed the [8.5.5 encode_json tag](http://www.lassosoft.com/tagswap/detail/Encode_JSON) from LassoStartup, so we are using the correct built-in method. The encode_json method fails for any and all parameters I throw at it from simple strings to arrays of maps. Upon restarting the site, encode_json resumes working for an hour or two, seemingly depending on load.

On 8.5.5, we don't have this problem. Does anyone have experience with this issue? Any advice regarding trying the [8.5.5 tag swap encode_json](http://www.lassosoft.com/tagswap/detail/Encode_JSON) to see if I can override the built-in method? Maybe it will work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the "-3" patch of 8.6.2 from the [LassoSoft Downloads](http://www.lassosoft.com/downloads_browse) seems to have solved the problem entirely.

-Justin

Answer (score 1):

Rick from [LassoTalk](http://www.lassosoft.com/LassoTalk/) helped with the following info:

> Hi Justin,
>
> I can't help but did recall this subject in another thread back in
>   August - the end result of that thread appears to be a bug report.
>
> http://lasso.2283332.n4.nabble.com/Encode-JSON-error-td4639201.html
>
> Very best regards,
>
> Rick

Comment: Try installing 8.6.2-3; that build fixed the tag corruption issue you appear to be having.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see if your 8.5.5 code you had in startup would work. If it's the same tag thats on TagSwap, then I would do the following:

1. Remove the check to see if it already exists (If: (Lasso_TagExists: 'Encode_JSON') == False;)
2. Add "-Priority='Replace'" to the method definition (Define_Tag: 'JSON', -Namespace='Encode_', -Priority='Replace', ....)

Note, I'm not sure if the built-in methods use namespacing like the above, or if they just use "define_tag('encode_json')". For this reason, I would recommend first trying to replace the built-in method with a one that just returns "It Works!". This will allow you to test it out and make sure you are replacing the already defined method. Once you've got the tag definition correct for replacing it, then let it do its thing.

Comment: For now I've taken a different approach and have "upgraded" to 8.6.2-3. I might've not been using the "-3" version, which was suggested on LassoTalk. So far today, not a single problem, and we would've normally had to restart Lasso a few times by now. Fingers crossed. Thanks for your contribution here. I will follow-up with another answer if 8.6.2-3 is a sustained fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code which I found from internet and used it.

It is working for me.

```
<?LassoScript
define_tag('jsonHash', -required='input',-type='array',
    -description='Takes a Lasso Array and outputs a json Hash. Lassosoft offers a complex json type but, not needed in this case.
    Outputs name/value pairs.This can and should be moved to a common location with other custom tags.');

    local('ret'='[');
    local('this'=string);
    iterate: #input, local:'x';
        local:'xSize' = #x->size;
        #this += '{';
        iterate: #x, local:'i';
            #this += '"' + #i->first + '":"' + decode_html(#i->second) + '"';
            if: #xSize != loop_count;
                #this += ",";
            /if;
        /iterate;
        #this += '}';
        if(#input->size != loop_count);
            #this += ',';
        /if;
    /iterate;

    #ret += #this + ']';
    return(#ret);
/define_tag;

encode_json("Arguement");
?>
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks